# Using sql variable for generating table in range

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, for-loop, impala

Using beeline
Query as below

```
create table code12.a1
from 
select b.id where category=1
and b.date between '2015-01-31' and '2015-01-01';
```

I want to loop the query such that i can use a1 belongs to (a1,a12) 
and use b.date as between 2015-01- to 2015-12 ( middle one being month)
Can i use For loop or while in Impala SQL queries
Please share.

Answer (score 0):

- Remove "from" -- syntax error
- Don't create lots of tables; keep similar data in a single table
- `between '2015-01-31' and '2015-01-01'` is backwards
- Please explain the underlying goal that lead you to this 'solution'.